Can 'the church which is in thy house' be a closer representation of the Body of Christ than formal, denominational, gatherings?
My question is not that which was asked previously Where should the church gather ? which was a question about how should persons gather in a locality and what arrangement should be made for that.
My question is different.
I live in England and I recently travelled elsewhere and was invited to attend a meeting where someone spoke from a platform and prayed and some verses were sung from a screen above us. But also my host invited me home and there we read through a book of the bible together, chapter by chapter alternately ; we sang a psalm and we knelt and prayed.
I realised that what we had done in the home had been more spiritual, more edifying and more charitable than the formal meeting in a large building.
If one, out of desire 'not to forsake the assembling together' meets in a formal setting and submits to an exterior form of worship which is not altogether satisfactory, then one may not feel that that gathering is a true representation of the 'church', that is to say the body of Christ and the house of God.
Is it the case that one may experience a closer representation of that which Christ builds ('I will build my church') in one's own home ?
And is that what Paul alludes to when he writes of 'the church which is in their house' Romans 16:3-5 and 'the church in thy house' Philemon 1:2 ?
This is no technical point or mere inquisitive inquiry. For those of us who believe we are seeing the end times and the appalling effects of an arising opposition to the gospel which 'uprises' (apostasis) and elbows out that which is truly of Christ in order to take over the 'temple' and sit within it 'as God' and 'being worshipped', 2 Thessalonians 2:4 - to us who see that happening, the reality of the church being 'in our house' is something that needs to be seriously thought about.
Is it the case that when Jesus Christ says 'where two or three are gathered together in my name there am I in the midst', Matthew 18:20, that what is done in the home may more closely align with his words than what one is doing publicly, for the sake of corporate conformity ?
My question is asked of those who are trinitarian and protestant.

Greet Priscilla and Aquila my helpers in Christ Jesus: Who have for my life laid down their own necks: unto whom not only I give thanks, but also all the churches of the Gentiles. Likewise greet the church that is in their house. [Romans 16:3-5 KJV]


... unto Philemon our dearly beloved, and fellowlabourer, And to our beloved Apphia, and Archippus our fellowsoldier, and to the church in thy house: [Philemon 1:2 KJV]


Sorry, but I don't see how this isn't a question of opinion. Whether we think/feel a small gathering is more like the Body of Christ than a large formal gathering is going to be different for everyone.

Nigel, I myself have found doctrines of men and doctrine of "times past" within religious denominations to typically be antithetical to doctrine for today which was written directly to the church, the body of Christ (Romans through Philemon).  Our discussions of late are more in line with true fellowship, I believe.  As a previous member of various denominations, I say there needs to be room on this site for non-denominational Christian Q & A.  Curiousdanni, do the right thing and make it happen! ;-)

@curiousdannii It's ok. I got a good answer and accepted it. Mission accomplished.

Formal, denominational gatherings can certainly appear to be devoid of genuinely biblical, Spirit-led worship. And, conversely, informal gatherings of Christians (in houses, or in gardens, or secretively in countryside hollows, as during the Killing Times in Scotland) can be clearly Spirit-led, closely representing the Body of Christ. History testifies to this, as well as the currently dire situation of formal religion.
It was always thus.
Only this morning I was reading of Paul's admonition to Galatian Christians, who (almost as soon as he had departed from them) had men come in to teach error which he called 'witchcraft', and those men he called 'ministers of Satan' for bringing them under the old veil of the law, under which the gospel is hid. He chides those Christians for being foolish, for if they went back under the law for fleshly perfection, Christ would profit them nothing, for he communicates by grace, not law. This is explained in William Huntington's 4th volume of sermons etc p. 466.
I give this as an example from the 1st. century which applies frighteningly in this 21st. century. Many formal denominations are corrupted by subtle infiltration of this 'witchcraft', beguiling members as were the Galatian Christians.
Ideally, all who see such dangerous error could stand up within such gatherings and point it out. Well, those who have tried in our day soon find themselves unwelcome in the formal denominations that keep clinging on to some form of legalism. They must then find their fellowship in the informal gatherings of Christians who understand this.
Given that it is a scriptural injunction for Christians not to forsake the gathering of themselves together, as some have the custom, it's clear that those who desire true Christian fellowship (as opposed to those who can hardly be bothered to meet formally) will eventually only find it amongst a few others, who might not even be local.
The question of degree of deviation in formal denominations is reaching a critical point, in view of the Lord's sudden return, when those who have not taken a stand on eschewing doctrinally wrong matters (which includes wrong morality) will be seen to be 'identified' by those who object to their biblical views, and effectively put out. Others may leave before they are shoved out. This time we are living in seems to be a time for facing up to issues such as raised in this question. Not everyone will yet think the degree of deviation in a formal denomination they are associated with warrants 'voting with their feet', only to discover that they are made so unwelcome that going elsewhere is the only option. The question is, where will they go to? To Jesus, who alone builds his Church, of course! He will bring together those who only want to follow him, as opposed to a denomination.
The straight answer to the straight question is, "Yes, a closer representation of the Body of Christ can be found in gatherings outwith formal, denominational structures."

It is also important to remember that every 'church' contains both tares and wheat; that every meeting in every denomination contains many unsaved.  Large gatherings are likely to have a higher percentage.

It was a good answer all the same, Anne.

@MikeBorden Yes, though the concept of 'every church' goes against the one Church Christ builds, with him as its head. This is where elders in every gathering are accountable to Christ if they allow 'tares' to so creep in to Christian gatherings that the 'wheat' becomes chocked. Mat. 13:25 the enemy sowing tares while believers sleep.
